# Static method X mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, oop, mysql-real-escape-string

i have the following static method in my class.

```
public static function GETSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = ""){}
```

inside this method i have these following instructions:

```
if(function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string")){
    $theValue = mysql_real_escape_string($theValue);
    echo "a: " . $theValue;
} else {
    $theValue = mysql_escape_string($theValue);
    echo "b: " . $theValue;
}
```

when i run this program, is printed on screen "a: ". This means that $theValue lost his value.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually connected to the database? You need an active connection for `mysql_real_escape_string()` to function. In any case, we can't really help without seeing all method's definition.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: Please show the entire method and the call to it.

Comment: What happens when you `echo $theValue` *before* calling `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: I'm not connected to the database yet. Surely this must be the problem. I will see PDO Data Objects now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because I was not connected to the database before call to `mysql_real_escape_string` function.